# Buffer Delay Calculation In Android HAL

Tags: android, hal

I didn't get this buffer delay calculation in android HAL.

```
bufDelay = (long)(((int64_t)(mInputFramesIn + mProcFramesIn) * 1000000000)
                                / AUDIO_HW_IN_SAMPLERATE);
```

I didn't understand why they are subtracting (mInputFramesIn + mProcFramesIn) with AUDIO_HW_IN_SAMPLERATE (i think the value of this macro will be 44,100).can anyone help me in this.

Comment: It would appear that the delay is the sum of two buffer sizes; the rest is just unit conversions.

Comment: But here mInputFramesIn is number of samples that are captured at 44,100 sample rate and mProcFramesIn is the number of frames that are read at 8k/16k/32 sample rate.How can we divide (mInputFramesIn + mProcFramesIn) with AUDIO_HW_IN_SAMPLERATE.

Comment: Likely your impression of what those two values represent is mistaken.  Perhaps this code is concerned with the actual hardware layer, upstream of any sample rate conversion to user sample rates.